# Django payments integration

Tags: python, django

I have a shopping cart rendered by view method A, I want to get the details in the cart to be submitted to the pesapal api, via a [pesapal package](https://github.com/odero/django-pesapal). I'm using the same method as the [sandbox app, PaymentView](https://github.com/odero/django-pesapal/blob/master/sandbox/testapp/views.py). The shopping cart has a checkout button which is intended to submit the data to the api. The Sandbox method simlpy gets the data as a dictionary (order_info) and feeds to a url (get_payment_url) which then feeds the api, thus when I open the template, the api's iframe dictates I am withrawing the amout specified in the dictionary. How can I submit data via the cart?

```
## Sandbox method submitting data to the api
class PaymentView(TemplateView, PaymentRequestMixin):
    template_name = 'payment/payment.html'
    # how the sandbox app submits data to api:

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(PaymentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        order_info = {
        'amount': '1000',
        'description': 'Payment for Stuff',
        'reference': 2,
        'email': 'you@email.com'
    }

    ctx['pesapal_url'] = self.get_payment_url(**order_info)
    return ctx

## view method A:
def show_cart(request, template_name="payment/cart.html"):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            cart.remove_from_cart(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            cart.update_cart(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Checkout':
            # submission to api should occur here 
    cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request)
    cart_subtotal = cart.cart_subtotal(request)
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# my url
urlpatterns = patterns('cart.views',
(r'^$', 'show_cart', { 'template_name': 'payment/cart.html' }, 'show_cart'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you would get off it quickly by letting django parse  your data to the template or in this case your cart. This can be done by letting your method return the data you want. Something like:

```
return render(request, 'yourpage.html', 
                {'yourvariable':yourvariable},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then just get your value in the template (cart in your case) like:

```
{{yourvariable}}
```

Then let the api do the rest.

Comment: but where would I make the api call and feed the data in the cart after I return the data ?

Comment: Hi yeah this totally worked!! I parsed the data via a new update_view method which made submitting to the api real smooth. This is what happens-- I modified the show_cart method such that it renders on a different tab in the same template that the data is being submitted thus after data is submitted, the user is directed to the cart tab with the table pre-filled and ready for submission

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation and the [source code](https://github.com/odero/django-pesapal), there doesn't seem to be a method to set any data. Do you have an example where this is done?

Comment: Actually there is, Are you referring to the data set to be sent to api? @Martin check out the method 'generate_payload' which generates an xml payload as a dictionary [here](https://github.com/odero/django-pesapal/blob/master/django_pesapal/views.py)

Comment: The data in my app is only available after a form submission thus I created a new update_view method which allows a user to edit their options one more time. On the same template there is a payments tab with the cart and since it's an update view, the item's data is pre-filled thus submitting is easier @Martin Hallén